# minifilter driver - obtaining account information

Tags: c, minifilter

Before i get too deep into it, i wanted to see if it was even possible.  The question is if the user's id or any sort of identifiable account information is exposed or can be retrieved in a minifilter driver.

Obviously it would probably be on me to do a lot of the legwork on actually identifying the user, but i didn't see anything that gave specific info on the user initiating the request.  I ran through a few of the samples and online documentation but was unable to find a struct or anything that seemed to have any useful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SID - can be retrieved by the minifilter driver.
Later this could help to identify user related information.

Following link has more information:

http://aonprog.wordpress.com/2009/02/16/how-to-get-sid-and-user-name-for-io-requests-in-file-mini-filter/

Comment: not sure how i missed that when googling for this, but that's exactly what i needed, thanks.